# Making an uneditable table with Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, tableview, xamarin.forms

I'm in the process of converting an Android app I made over to Xamarin.Forms for use in iOS and Windows Phone.

What I'm trying to do:

[image]

I want to make a simple 2 column wide table. I followed [this guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview/#TableView_Structure) however the entry cells were editable with no property to turn it off, I also need to be able to modify these entries easily (through code).

What I currently have:

```
var section = new TableSection() { 
    new EntryCell  { Label = "Chest", Text = "0" },
};

TableView tableView = new TableView
        {
            IsEnabled = false,
            Root = new TableRoot
            {
                section
            }
        };
```

EDIT: Already tried a TextCell, same deal, check this screenshot out

[image]

Also adds a bunch of random lines after my textentry

[image]

In a perfect world, I'd like something similar to an HTML table.

I saw a different thread where someone suggested a listview, but I don't see how I could make a table with that.

I tried many different setups with a Grid, but it doesn't seem to be working

```
        Grid grid = new Grid
        {
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            RowDefinitions =
            {
                 new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Absolute) }
            },
            ColumnDefinitions =
            {
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Absolute) },
                new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Absolute) }
            }
        };
        grid.Children.Add(txtChest);
        grid.Children.Add(txtChestResults);
```

Comment: Use a TextCell instead of an EntryCell.

Comment: Already tried that, still allows text modifying. See my most recent edit.

Comment: I'm sorry, but a TextCell does not allow editing. It's for simply displaying text.

Comment: Just double checked, and it appears you are correct.. will post back soon

Answer (score 0):

I'm not marking this as the accepted answer for a few days in case someone has a better solution. I'm open to suggestions, since if I had to add another column to this "table", this solution wouldn't work.

As of this date (June 11th, 2016), I have to say that TableView is too buggy to be practical. There's a consistent complaints of extra spaces, also when you touch the textviews, they look like they're about to perform an action (hard to explain without a video). They're static text, they shouldn't respond to touch.

Here is how I made my simple two column table (although it's more like a tabular view than a conventional table). Cliffnotes? Several horizontally oriented StackLayouts inside one vertical oriented StackLayout. I position one Label on the far left, and the other on the far right. End result looks something like this:
[image]

```
    //Result Items

/* Start chest */
Label txtChest = new Label
{
    Text = "Chest",
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand

};
Label txtChestResults = new Label
{
    Text = "0",
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand

};
/* End chest */

/* Start Biceps */
Label txtBiceps = new Label
{
    Text = "Biceps",
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand
};
Label txtBicepsResults = new Label
{
    Text = "0",
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand

};
/* End Biceps */

/* Start Forearms */
Label txtForearms = new Label
{
    Text = "Forearms",
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand
};
Label txtForearmsResults = new Label
{
    Text = "0",
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand
};
/* End Forearms */


/* Start Neck */
Label txtNeck = new Label
{
    Text = "Neck",
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand
};
Label txtNeckResults = new Label
{
    Text = "0",
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand
};
/* End Neck */


/* Start Thighs */
Label txtThighs = new Label
{
    Text = "Thighs",
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand
};
Label txtThighsResults = new Label
{
    Text = "0",
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand
};
/* End Thighs */

/* Start Calves */
Label txtCalves = new Label
{
    Text = "Calves",
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand
};
Label txtCalvesResults = new Label
{
    Text = "0",
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand
};
/* End Calves */

//Chest StackLayout
StackLayout chestLayout = new StackLayout
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
};
chestLayout.Children.Add(txtChest);
chestLayout.Children.Add(txtChestResults);


//biceps layout
StackLayout bicepsLayout = new StackLayout
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
};
bicepsLayout.Children.Add(txtBiceps);
bicepsLayout.Children.Add(txtBicepsResults);


//forearms layout
StackLayout forearmsLayout = new StackLayout
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
};
forearmsLayout.Children.Add(txtForearms);
forearmsLayout.Children.Add(txtForearmsResults);


//Neck layout
StackLayout neckLayout = new StackLayout
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
};
neckLayout.Children.Add(txtNeck);
neckLayout.Children.Add(txtNeckResults);


//Thighs layout
StackLayout thighsLayout = new StackLayout
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
};
thighsLayout.Children.Add(txtThighs);
thighsLayout.Children.Add(txtThighsResults);

//Calves layout
StackLayout calvesLayout = new StackLayout
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
};
calvesLayout.Children.Add(txtCalves);
calvesLayout.Children.Add(txtCalvesResults);

StackLayout resultsLayout = new StackLayout
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical
};
resultsLayout.Children.Add(chestLayout);
resultsLayout.Children.Add(bicepsLayout);
resultsLayout.Children.Add(forearmsLayout);
resultsLayout.Children.Add(neckLayout);
resultsLayout.Children.Add(thighsLayout);
resultsLayout.Children.Add(calvesLayout);


//add chest results
layout.Children.Add(resultsLayout);
```